# Material Design icons not loading

Tags: css, javafx, webview, google-material-icons

I've built a single page app with VanillaJS, Webpack and Material Design Lite. The application runs fine in a browser and is rendered correctly.

I would like to get this webapp in a JavaFX Webview. Everything is working well, excepting that the Material Icons are not rendered.

I've tried this :

```
Font.loadFont(        
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff").toExternalForm(), 10
);
```

But it didn't work.

I've tried to encode Material Design icons font directly as base64 in the css file, using this Webpack configuration:

```
{
     test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
     include: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'mdl-pack', 'dist', 'icons'),
     loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
}
```

Didn't work too.

I've used the [webview debugger](https://github.com/mohamnag/javafx_webview_debugger) and can see that woff font is loaded by the webview.

Does somebody already loaded icons font in JavaFX Webview? How do you proceed?

Comment: i have been looking throw these while a go and ended up using this : https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx

if you found better solution kindly help

Comment: doesn't work for me. This library seems to enable WebFont in JavaFx UI, not in Webviews...